# How to run python file from windows?

Tags: python-2.7

i have installed following packages to my windows machine -

python-numpy

python-matplotlib

python-pyside

but when i m running a command "python script.py" it says python is not an internal or external command

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Python to your environmental variables.

More info under this link
http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html